# How to handle double clicks in visio 2013 stencil shape master

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I have created a stencil from a shape in visio 2013. This shape master has multiple shapes which are grouped together. I have used shape protection to prevent people from deleting internal grouped shapes and adding any text to any of the shaped.

I have got a separate text box below the shape and I want to edit this text box whenever users double click anywhere in the shape. How do I go about do this?

This is a pattern I have seen all of the standard vision stencils Microsofts makes available e.g. Azure stencil. Just not sure how do they do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to this behavior is NOT to include a separate text box as part of your group. Instead you want to edit the text of the group itself. By default, the text on a group is placed in the middle, but you can use the Text Blook Tool (lower right in the Tools group on the Home tab) to reposition the text block.

BTW, an easier way to lock access to subshapes within a group is to set the group selection property to "Group only". That prevents users from selecting the subshapes, and if they can't select them, they can't delete them or add text to them. To change the group behavior setting, turn on the Developer tab, select the group, and then click the Behavior button. In the resulting dialog, make the highlighted change: [behavior dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PojQJ.png).

Finally, to set the double-click behavior so it allows the user to edit the text of the group, click the Double-Click tab in the Behavior dialog and verify the setting shown here: [double-click behavior tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vgJL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the shape's double-click behavior to edit the shape's text.

Edit the master shape, and select the parent shape.  Then open the Developer tab, and select Behavior.  Pick the Double-Click tab, and select 'Edit shape's text' and click OK.

That should do it, assuming the parent shape text is what you want to change.  If it's a child shape, then that gets trickier, since you can't double-click a child shape without first selecting the parent (unless the parent selection behavior is child-first, which makes it harder to select the whole group).